# Remove specific dropdown option from Kendo dropdownlist using jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, html-input

I have tried and searched the internet trying to figure this out but still haven't found an exact answer.  Removing an item from a standard issued select dropdown is pretty easy,  the code is:    $("#dropdownlistID option[value='optiontoremove']").remove();

How do i do this with Kendo Dropdownlist,    something along the lines of $("#dropdownlistID").data("kendoDropDownList").whateverhere.remove.

There's already an answer here that points out how to remove an item of a certain index position but that doesn't answer the question of how to remove an option with a certain value as index positions may change.   An example of what is needed is say you have these elements from a kendo dropdownlist..  How do you remove (or hide) the option with say "cruiser"?

```
select
  option value="volvo"  Volvo
  option value="saab"  Saab
  option value="mercedes"  Mercedes
  option value="audi"  Audi 
  option value="cruiser"  Cruiser
  option value="blah"  blah
  option value="blah2"  blah2
select
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<input id="color" style="width: 100%;" />
<input type="button" onclick="removeItem()" value="removeItem" />
...........
...........
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = [
                    { text: "Volvo", value: "volvo" },
                    { text: "Audi", value: "audi" },
                    { text: "Cruiser", value: "cruiser" }
        ];

        // create DropDownList from input HTML element
        $("#color").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "text",
            dataValueField: "value",
            dataSource: data,
        });


    });
    function removeItem() {
        var ddl = $("#color").data("kendoDropDownList");
        var oldData = ddl.dataSource.data();
        var dataLength = oldData.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
            var item = oldData[i];
            if (item.value == "cruiser"){ // Here 'value' is 'dataValueField' field
                ddl.dataSource.remove(item);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply..    Wasn't working and when i did an alert on item.value,  example   alert(item.value);   it was giving me 4 alerts for the 4 items in the collection,   All saying 'undefined'.     So basically item.value is undefined..   Any suggestions?    Getting real close to solving this,   Thanks for the snippet

Comment: Nevermind Jayesh,  figured it out..    On item.value i needed to set value to name of dataValueField in the Control..     Thanks a million..

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use jQuery to remove a specific item from the dropdown list.

You can achieve what you want by using the Kendo DataSource object and its MVVM pattern.

Your HTML will be as follows:

```
<input id='dropdownlist' data-role="dropdownlist"
       data-text-field="ProductName"
       data-value-field="ProductID"
       data-bind="value: selectedProduct,
                  source: products" />

<button id="button" type="button">Remove current item</button>

<br />

<input class='k-textbox' id='specificItem' />
<button id="removeSpecificButton" type="button">Remove specific item</button>
```

And your JavaScript will be:

```
// Use a viewModel, so that any changes to the model are instantly applied to the view.
// In this case the view is the dropdownlist.
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
  selectedProduct: null,

  products: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
        dataType: "jsonp"
      }
    }
  })
});

kendo.bind($("#dropdownlist"), viewModel);

$("#removeSpecificButton").kendoButton({
  click: function(e) {
    // Find the item specified in the text box
    viewModel.products.filter( { 
                         field: "ProductName", 
                         operator: "eq", 
                         value: $('#specificItem').val() });
    // Apply the view to find it
    var view = viewModel.products.view();
    //remove the item from the datasource      
    viewModel.products.remove(view[0]);
    // disable the filter
    viewModel.products.filter({});
  }
});

// Set-up the button so that when it is clicked
// it determines what the currently selected dropdown item is
// and then deletes it.
$("#button").kendoButton({
  click: function(e) {
    // Determine which item was clicked
    var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList"); 
    var dataItem = dropdownlist.dataItem();

    // Remove that item from the datasource
    viewModel.products.remove(dataItem);
  }
});
```

I have written an example of this working here:

http://dojo.telerik.com/@BenSmith/aCEXI/11

Note how the DataSource's "filter" method has been used to specify the exact item (in this case ProductName) to be removed. After the item has been removed the filter can be removed to display the data without the no longer required item.

I've also included a facility where the current selected item can be removed for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI databound widgets use their [`dataSource` instances](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#fields-dataSource)' API to [`add`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-add), [`insert`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-insert) or [`remove`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-remove) items.

If you don't want to hard-code an item's index, then [`get`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-get) it via its ID. For this to work, the ID field must be defined in [`schema.model.id`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.model)

http://dojo.telerik.com/aFUGe

Note that the above example does not configure the Kendo UI DataSource for [CRUD operations](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud), which means that all changes will only occur on the client, and not be persisted to the remote service.

If your DropDownList data items have no ID, then the only way to find an item by its value is to obtain all items with the [`data`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-data) method, and iterate them until the correct one is found.